# How to ignore all fields but one in root element in JSON with Retrofit?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm very new with retrofit and I'm struggling to parse my JSON response.
My JSON looks like that:

```
{
  "id": "111111",
  "title": "title place holder",
  "author": {
    "name": "author place holder"
  },
  "summary": "summary place holder",
  "type": {
    "value": "value place holder"
  },
  "entry": []
}
```

Now, I don't care about all the elements at the root level except the entry array.
I created a model for Entry object and ignored everything else in the root, when I tried to get the data with Retrofit, I got the following error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Here is my Model for the Entry object (I added annotations only to the fields that I need):

```
public class Entry
{
    @SerializedName("type")
    private Type type;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("summary")
    private String summary;

    private String id;

    @SerializedName("published")
    private String published;

    private String updated;

    @SerializedName("content")
    private Content content;

    @SerializedName("link")
    private Link link;

    @SerializedName("media_group")
    private List<MediaGroup> mediaGroup;

    private Author author;

   //GETTERS and SETTERS ....
}
```

Here's my API interface which defines the GET call:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("link_json.json")
    Call<List<Entry>> getPosts();

}
```

This is how I start Retrofit:

```
public void start() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

    Call<List<Entry>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts();
    call.enqueue(this);

}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @Ashish I added the relevant code that I use.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you're expecting JSON array as response but you're getting JSON object. So could you please ensure that your server and your client has same data type.

Now error is because your server is sending JSON object which has the **entry** JSON array which i believe you want. So best way would be to replace `List<Entry>` with some pojo class say Response(which will be your JSON object) and from this response you'll get entry JSON array. BTW use this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert your json schema to POJO